# Moving to a specific position in a text widget tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, text-widget

i wanted to know if it's possible to move to a specific position in a text widget in tkinter.
I implemented search in text widget and wanted to implement "next" and "previous" methods for my search to move across the text widget. Is it possible to do?
Thanks for any help.

Here is a code for my method:

```
def find():
    xml.tag_delete("search")
    xml.tag_configure("search", background="green")
    start="1.0"
    if len(fi.get()) > 0:
        xml.mark_set("insert", xml.search(fi.get(), start))
        while True:
            pos = xml.search(fi.get(), start, END) 
            if pos == "": 
                break       
            start = pos + "+%dc" % len(fi.get()) 
            xml.tag_add("search", pos, "%s + %dc" % (pos,len(fi.get())))
```

`fi` is an entry field for search pattern. `xml` is a text field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text widget has *marks*, which are in effect named positions. The insertion cursor is defined by the mark `"insert"` (and the tkinter constant `INSERT`). You can move this index using the `mark_set` method.

For example, this moves the insertion cursor to line 3, character 14:

```
the_widget.mark_set("insert", "3.14")
```

If you want to make sure the new insert position is visible you can use the `see` method, which will scroll the widget enough for the given index to be visible:

```
the_widget.see("insert")
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, i tried it already. Please look at my code above. Maybe i'm using it wrongly, but it doesn't move to a first occurrence of search. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You must be computing the index incorrectly then. Calling mark_set is the only way to do what you want, and if you give it a valid index, it is guaranteed to work.

Comment: i debugged it and see position is 87.26. It's properly highlithed but it doesn't move to it, i have to scroll all the way down to this index to see it.

Comment: @BigOldTree: setting the "insert" mark doesn't guarantee that it will be visible. Are you asking about moving the cursor, or making the cursor visible? Those are two different things.

Comment: Bryan i want to move to a first occurrence, if it's not visible then scroll down for it. Is it possible?

Comment: @BigOldTree: yes, of course it's possible. `the_widget.see("insert")`.

Comment: You know Bryan, you are the best :) Like a moving tkinter encyclopedia ready to answer right away.